# Java: is it possible to use a parameterized type into another parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics, jpa, type-conversion

Not sure how to title this question but will try to explain. I'm trying to use JPA criteria API and have run into some issues;

I have the following entities;

```
public class Sword extends Item {}
public class InventoryItem<T extends Item> {}
```

And this is what I'm trying to get working (this does't compile unless it returns `List<InventoryItem>` but I want it to return `List<InventoryItem<Sword>>`):

```
public List<InventoryItem<Sword>> get() {
  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<InventoryItem> cq = cb.createQuery(InventoryItem.class);
  Root<InventoryItem> o = cq.from(InventoryItem.class);
  .........
  List<InventoryItem> resultList = query.getResultList();
  return resultList; 
}
```

I tried the following;

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<InventoryItem<Sword>> cq = cb.createQuery(InventoryItem<Sword>.class);
    Root<InventoryItem<Sword>> o = cq.from(InventoryItem<Sword>.class);
```

but get the following errors;

InventoryItem cannot be resolved to a variable.

Sword cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Im pretty sure you can input the exact type, instead of a placeholder. `class Test<OtherType> { }`. Im not on a computer right now, so test it out and let me know

Comment: I did try this early but the subclass is not a real entity so using the CriteriaBuilder fails at runtime when it tries to execute the query.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a real entity"?

Comment: InventoryItem is one entity that maps to table "Inventory_Item", so this table holds all the player-item relationship. If I extend it to make a class SwordInventoryItem extends InventoryItem<Sword>, hibernate fails as it is not an entity. Turning it into an entity is useless is it would make multiple inventory tables.

Answer (score 0):

`InventoryItem<Sword>.class` is an illegal expression in Java. You cannot apply a generic to a class literal; even if you could, the generic would be erased at compile time while returning the same Class object.

To convince the compiler to treat your class literal as a generic expression, you'll need to cast it:

```
CriteriaQuery<InventoryItem<Sword>> cq =
    cb.createQuery((Class) InventoryItem.class);
Root<InventoryItem<Sword>> o = cq.from((Class) InventoryItem.class);
```

or

```
CriteriaQuery<InventoryItem<Sword>> cq =
    (CriteriaQuery) cb.createQuery(InventoryItem.class);
Root<InventoryItem<Sword>> o =
    (Root) cq.from(InventoryItem.class);
```

...though I haven't tested those locally, and they will require a use of `@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})` because Java can't guarantee the safety of casts without generics: you're taking type safety into your own hands here.

(Note: This is why libraries like Guava and Guice introduce concepts like [TypeToken](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained) and [TypeLiteral](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) respectively, to embody Class literals with generic types.)

Comment: unfortunately neither of those worked :( I get compile error with 'Cannot cast to'

Comment: Sorry about that. I knew I was forgetting something.